# Write code inside ASPxMemo aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

i have this aspx code that used to work (on .net 2.0):

```
<Templates>
   <EditForm>
      <div>
         <dxe:ASPxMemo runat="server" ID="Memo1" Text='<%#Bind("field1")%>' Width="100%" Height="60px" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#E6E6E6"></dxe:ASPxMemo>
...
```

Now i'm trying to re-use it in the same context but using .net 3.5, but i got an error. I'll try to translate it:

> Can't edit Controls because the control contains blocks of code (like
>   <% ... %>).

so i tried to do via vb.net code this:

```
Memo1.Text = #Bind("field1")
```

but looks like a can't access Memo1 because of protection level

how i can make this work again?

edit: found a tutorial here http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/GridEditing/EditFormTemplate.aspx

but the tutorial uses bracket insde Text too!

Comment: Is AspxMemo is a third party control? If so, I guess you might be facing this error due to compatibility issue, if you are using third party control for 2.0 in 3.5.

Comment: Can you provide code of outer element (tag). Is it some kind of grid or datalist?

Comment: @Ali.NET: yes, it's from devexpress (www.devexpress.com) but seems like it is an old component, i can't find lot of info about it

Comment: @Vishal Vaishya: its inside a <dxwgv:ASPxGridView>!

Comment: @HypeZ use updated DevX controls for framework 3.5 then.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Looks like that ASPxGridView doesn't like `<% ... %>` code inside the **page header**.

Some days ago i added in my master page's `<head>` a simple `<% Response.Write() %>` and the entire **ASPxGridView** failed because of that.

Moving that code outside the header resulted in a **working** ASPxGridView, that was not a problem of .NET framework version!